# How is this webpage updating? Firebug shows no net activity?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

[http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^FTSE&ql=0](http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5EFTSE&ql=0)

I have 'net' enabled on firebug but I cannot see any activity whatsoever, yet the price is being updated?

Comment: I think they are using the [hidden iframe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Hidden_iframe) technique.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can get this data from a Java or C# app?

Comment: Get the data from a different source instead. That one is a mediocre source, you'll need a custom parsing algorithm and a permanently open HTTP connection to extract that data.

Comment: Sorry to ask a new question, but is there anyway I can get my data from this source/graph? http://goldprice.org/live-gold-price.html

Comment: Find a damn public REST API -.- [Google Finance API is a good place to start](http://www.google.com/support/finance/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79151)

Comment: Except google don't offer gold commodity prices, which is why I didn't use it

Answer (score 3):

Using streamapi. Open Net tab and look at 
[http://streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com/streamer/1.0?s=^FTSE,USD=X&......](http://streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com/streamer/1.0?s=%5EFTSE,USD=X&o=AAL.L,ARM.L,BARC.L,BLT.L,ENRC.L,IAP.L,IMT.L,ISAT.L,ITV.L,LMI.L,%5EFTSE,%5EDJI,%5EGSPC,%5EIXIC,%5ETYX,%5ERUT&k=c10,g00,h00,l10,p20,t10&j=c10,l10,p20,t10&r=0&callback=parent.yfs_u1f&mktmcb=parent.yfs_mktmcb&gencallback=parent.yfs_gencb&region=GB&lang=en-GB&localize=1&mu=1)

size of this file increases always

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can 'grab' this data?

Answer (score 2):

That's a nifty trick, I'd say! Look in the network tab at the very last entry (something like GET 1.0...). Then open the tab "Answer". You see, that this file never stops loading and spits out script tags.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can 'grab' this data?